# How to invoke a child models scope from parent in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

Please help me to find a way to invoke a child scope inside parent scope. is there any way by which i can achieve that.

**The scenario is follows:**

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :shows
  scope :active_shows, ->{
    joins(:shows)
  }
  ...
end

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :film
  scope :active_for_now, ->{
   ...
  }
  ...
end
```

From the above Eg, i want to know how to invoke scope `active_for_now` from `active_shows`. `show` table has fields `start_time` and `end_time` when i call `Film.active_shows` have to get all Films having active show for the current time.

please help me if there any solution for that and please correct if i gone wrong.

Comment: Hello, could you describe a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Bohdan i have updated question with better example i guess please go through it.

Comment: it shouldn't be a scope.  declare another `has_many` association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused on the scope and association names and whether they are representing a relationship I'm not seeing but to invoke a scope that is defined on the `has_many`, you can use [#merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :bs
  scope :abs, ->{
    joins(:bs).merge(B.bas)
  }
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a separate [`has_many` association with a scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many):

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shows
  has_many :active_shows, class_name: 'Show', ->{ Show.active_for_now }
end
```

The main advantage is that you can use the association directly when joining:

```
@films = Film.eager_load(:active_shows).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: I would call it `currently_active` though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but i'm afraid this won't work for my case. has_many association lets us to accomplish one to many relation right. What i'm looking for was eg: by using the scope Show.active_for_now i'l get all the shows which are currently active now what i expected to achieve is when i call the scope Film.active_shows i wanted to get all the Film which are currently active.

Comment: Thats a very a confusing name.